# Using c++ libraries source in project

Tags: c++, static-libraries

I am looking to use c++ library's source in the project instead of using dll or library files because I don't want to switch between library file formats depending on the operating system. I am specifically inquiring about building libcurl in Visual Studio 2013 by putting the source folder into my project.

I want my file structure to be:

```
Header Files
     src (libcurl)
     ...other files

Source Files
    cpp Files here
```

Whenever I try to add the files to my project I get errors such as 
"Mac file format detected please convert source file to DOS or UNIX format" or
"#unexpected in macro definition"

I tried saving the files to DOS in Visual Studio but I still get the same errors.

I want to emulate the Java's Jar system but instead use a source folder.

[image: Libcurl Extracted]

^I want to take headers and source files from the above directory and "copy and paste" them into a subfolder in my project called "libcurl src." What is the best course of action?

Answer (score 0):

looks like your files were created on Unix, where the newline char has a different form than from Windows - usually on modern text editors (such as 
[UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/)) have a feature to convert the files to DOS format.
you should try and convert all your files...

Comment: Is converting the only problem? Or is there more worked involved then copy and pasting the "src" folder

Comment: Compiling C++ external libraries into your project is nothing different than having a multiple source files project. so it should be fine.